# How to mount a drive when in xmonad using terminal?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount, ntfs, xmonad

So, I've been itroduced to XMONAD by now, and he tiling window manager seems classic.
I'm stuck when I have to access a file from another drive (It's a NTFS drive), so I found the way to list the Drives with their label (Which I gave them in Windows 7).

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL
```

which results the below-

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL
NAME    LABEL 
sda
  ├─sda1
  ├─sda2
  ├─sda5  Game Drive
  ├─sda6  TJsVOLUME
  ├─sda7  Softwares
  ├─sda8
  ├─sda9  Professional Work Drive
  └─sda10
 sdb
  └─sdb1
  sr0
```

But I couldn't get success mounting with this

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o ro /dev/sda1
```

I'm a newbie and I know only few about this command.

Answer (score 0):

`cifs` is the type for Windows/Samba shared directories, not NTFS partitions. Assuming you are really aiming to mount `sda1` (it doesn't have a label, are you sure that's the one you want?), try:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Your files should be available in `/mnt`.

Comment: I tried this, but is still not working. Any other info. you require from my system?

Comment: @RAWbot well yes, the error that `mount` threw and the output of `sudo parted -l` could be useful.